# NuGet - Given a type name or a DLL, how can I find the NuGet package?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, nuget

I find blog posts about implementing stuff like OWIN integration or `IAuthenticationFilter` in Web API 2, but I can never work out what NuGet package(s) I need.

I seem to randomly Google stuff and look through GitHub projects, other blogs hoping for some clue.

Considering everything is going NuGet, is there a better way? A massive index of Package > Assembly > Types?

Comment: And what would you do if that assembly were in 3000 packages?

Comment: I'm looking for the package containing the type, `Namespace.Something.SomeType`. There's a problem here. It's becoming hard to know what packages to reference.

Comment: And a type can exist in more than one package.. it can exist in ithousands of packages...  What you're asking for doesn't make sense.

Comment: So thousands of packages own the type `System.Web.Http.Filters.IAuthenticationFilter`, is that what you're telling me?

Comment: Who said anything about "own".  Packages can contain any number of assemblies.  It doesn't mean they "own" them.  They're just distributing them.  If it's an open source component, there could be many forks of it in different packages.  You're really not thinking about the exponential explosion of data this would require.  Not just from the package side, but from the users side to dig through that haystack.

Comment: MVC's documentation is sub-optimal. Its types are spread out over tens of packages with tons of assemblies. It's hard to find where to obtain which assembly. On the other hand, you don't go _"I know, I'll implement `IAuthenticationFilter`"_. You must have read about it somewhere. Doesn't that source mention which packages were used?

Comment: @CodeCaster Not always, in fact, often not. And there are more and more packages.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch If I make a package, I could easily list out the new types I've borne into the world. If I'm using someone else's types, I'm not repackaging them, I'm depending on another package (that itself could list its types).

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch And in response to your very first question, I'd rank those 3,000 packages by popularity.

Comment: Yes, in some cases developers may make a type a dependency, in others they may compile it into their assembly.

Answer (score 3):

There is exactly what you want and it's called reverse package search but only for ASP.NET 5 packages - at least for now. You can make your search here : [Reverse Package Search](http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/)

Example query: [Search for System.String](http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/?q=System.String)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work (right this minute, at least), but a decent stab at the problem. So I can't +1 yet.

Answer (score 0):

I've interestingly just found that VS 2015 suggests packages by type name.

See, **Add Missing NuGet Packages in ASP.NET 5** in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/04/29/new-asp-net-features-and-fixes-in-visual-studio-2015-rc.aspx

Maybe the answer is to wait for VS vNext, but surely there's an open API this system is using and maybe a way to search via NuGet.org?

Comment: That is functionality that already exists in extensions like ReSharper.  All it's doing is taking a whitelist of known system types, as well as packages already in your soluition (but not in your project) and what not.  It's not going to search through the entire nuget repository.